# How to assign allowed payment methods to certain customers?

Tags: magento

I have several payment methods on my magento 1.6 shop and a number of registered customers. I'd like some customers to be able to access all payment methods and some customers just one or two of payment methods. How to allow certain payment methods to some customers but not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will require customization. Your best bet may be to use a module. See

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/netz98magento/extension/7590/n98_customergroupcheckout

and

http://amasty.com/shipping-payment-by-group.html

for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a custom payment method.

Then use the `isAvailable($quote = null)` method to return true or false depending on if the customer has access to that payment method.

Or, if you want a quick solution. Edit the existing payment method's `isAvailable` method to serve your needs. But this isn't as future proof as rolling your own payment method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. What you need to do is to create different customer groups and assign your customers (manually or programatically) to these groups.

Just go to "Customers -> Custumer groups -> Add new group" and create a new group. In that same window, you can select the allowed payment methods for that group.

To assign a customer to a particular group, go to "customers -> manage customers" and select that particular customer. In the second tab there is for the group of that customer. Just select the one that you think is appropriate and he or she will see only the payment methods, that you assigned to that group earlier.

Comment: The only options of customer group that I can change are "Group name" and "Tax class", there is nothing regarding payment methods or otherwise I wouldn't have raised this question.

Comment: At least you could do it in Enterprise.